# Want to use the same function in every class

Tags: java, android, function

I am developing an android application. Now i have created one function which create custom dialog box and i want this dialog box to display on every activity. So i need to call this function at every activity. But as the syntax of custom dialog (e.g. Dialog d = new Dialog(home.this)).home is the name of the activity where i have created the function so i am not ale to use this function in any other activity. And i haven't use android that much. So give me good example to solve my problem. [Here is my code](http://pastebin.com/4p0nVmts)

Comment: It gives me Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException. As my other activity want able to execute home,this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is sample code code of using `AlertDialog` in all activity.

crate one class file like as `allmethod.java`

and add this code in that class

```
public static void showAlert(Activity act,String msg)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
            alert.setMessage(msg).setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {   
                }
            }).show();
        }
```

and you can use from any class like as

```
allmethod.showAlert(Activity,"Message");
```

**In your case..**

```
public void SearchDialog(Context ctx){
           final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ctx);
       dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogsearch);
       dialog.setTitle("       Enter The Text to Search");
       dialog.setCancelable(true);

       final EditText Text = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.EdText);

       Button buttonOK = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
       buttonOK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View v) {
                   String SearchText = Text.getText().toString();

               prefsPrivate =getSharedPreferences(Login.PREFS_PRIVATE,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                   Editor prefsPrivateEdit=prefsPrivate.edit();                        
                   prefsPrivateEdit.putString("Text",SearchText);
                   prefsPrivateEdit.commit();
                   Intent i = new Intent(ctx,SearchTask.class);
                   startActivity(i);
                   dialog.cancel();
           }
       });

       Button buttonCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
       buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.cancel();

           }
       });
       dialog.show();
   }
```

Comment: Thnx for your suggetion bur what to right in the place of Home.this while calling the Intent. coz i have to use it in other classes also.

Comment: you can you ctx instead of Home.this in intent

Comment: Ya it solve my problem but i have other problem now. I got nullPointer Exception at the line :prefsPrivate =getSharedPreferences(Login.PREFS_PRIVATE,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: r u sure error it on that line? plz check again it may be error on another line

Comment: When i commented that line now error comes on the other line.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3490/discussion-between-kushal-shah-and-capdroid)

Comment: sorry i cant able to come there

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `Context` parameter to your `SearchDialog()` constructor.

Make it like this:

```
   public SearchDialog(Context context){
        //....
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either define your own Interface and implement for every class, or make the main Activity method static (as long as it wont need to access anything in dynamic objects that aren't method arguments).

Answer (score 0):

final class Uutil {

public void static func() {

}

}

then do it in your classes:

```
class A {
public void f() {
Uutil.func();
}
}
```